# How to do action injection for MVC 3 using Autofac?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, missingmethodexception

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 3 application trying to take advantage of controller action injection as described [here](http://alexmg.com/post/2010/05/16/Introducing-Action-Injection-with-Autofac-ASPNET-MVC-Integration.aspx).

Controller constructor injection works without any issues, but I can't seem to get action injection to work.

I've set up Autofac in Global.asax like this:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.Register<ITestInject>(c => new TestInject { TestString = "hi" });

builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).InjectActionInvoker();

var container = builder.Build();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

And my controller has an action like this:

```cs
public ActionResult Test(ITestInject testInject)
{
        return View(testInject);
}
```

The TestInject/ITestInject class/interface is defined as :

```cs
public interface ITestInject
{
    string TestString { get; }
}
public class TestInject : ITestInject
{
    public string TestString { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to navigate to the the Test action, I see this error:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> *Cannot create an instance of an interface.*
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> ```
> [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
>    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
>    System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +199
>    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +572
>    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317
>    Autofac.Integration.Mvc.ExtensibleActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +122
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +117
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
>    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
>    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10 
>    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b_5() +37
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b_0() +21
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b_7(IAsyncResult ) +12
>    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b_d() +50
>    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b_0(Action f) +7
>    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
> ```
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm using Autofac version 2.4.5.724.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Action injection is turned off by default in the current Autofac MVC3 implementation.

To enable it, pass a parameter to `ExtensibleActionInvoker`:

```
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>()
    .As<IActionInvoker>()
    .WithParameter("injectActionMethodParameters", true);
```

This was quite a recent change and some documentation will need updating - sorry about the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
builder.Register<ITestInject>(c => new TestInject { TestString = "hi" });
```

The first parameter in any `Register` method is the *concrete service* you want to register. Following that type comes the "how to instantiate", and then parameters that define the actual interface to expose the service as. You get the exception because Autofac tries to instantiate the implementation, which in the case above is an interface. Obviously, no constructor is found on an interface type.

Now look at this:

```
builder.Register<TestInject>(c => new TestInject { TestString = "hi" }).As<ITestInject>();
```

This approach IMO is one of Autofacs strengths compared to other DI frameworks. Where others start out the registration with the interface you want to expose and ends up with the implementation, Autofac starts with the actual implementation and ends up with the interface. This makes for cleaner syntax especially in cases where one concrete implementation can be exposed as several interfaces, all in one registration.

Comment: Not so in this case - the generic parameter type is ignored for most purposes and should actually be excluded.

Comment: Ahhrg, assumption is STILL the mother of all failures :)

Comment: I hear ya, still gets me every time :)